# How to translate string-array using the Android Studio Translations Editor

Tags: android, string, language-translation

In my strings.xml I have several string-arrays. I would like to translate them in the same way as I have translated other strings - using the Translations Editor in Android Studio. However, I cannot see the string-arrays in the Translations Editor. Is there any way how can I use the Translations Editor for the string-array as well as for strings? What is the best practise for translating string-arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let the array to use the string in strings.xml like following:

In arrays.xml:

```
<string-array name="countries">
    <item>@string/contry_option_0</item>
    <item>@string/contry_option_1</item>
</string-array>
```

In strings.xml:

```
<string name="country_option_0">Japan</string>
<string name="country_option_1">Thailand</string>
```

After doing that, you can see the key `contry_option_0` and `contry_option_1` in Translations Editor.